# How to remove a specific href from a top-menu link in Magento

Tags: magento2, php, url, menu

i post before several day this one

Hello I am trying to make 3 items on menu to be not click-able and I want to ask how to remove a specific href from a top-menu link in magento? (I don't want to remove from all menu items just for 3 as you can see here http://prntscr.com/kqtt77) also I don't want to use href="#" any suggest?

well when i set url from admin panel it duplicate the urls... after flush and shows me in db this

```
<a href="https://url/"https://url/" class="level0 dropdown-
```

any suggest??? :/

Comment: Do you have any specific class or id for those menu items?

Comment: nope only id... i put # http://prntscr.com/ksnoen look the pic but look on db cache http://prntscr.com/ksnoqw

Comment: Can you add any extra class to those links where you want no link?

Comment: i want those url to be not clickable http://prntscr.com/ksowfz and add custom cursor default

Comment: For for those you need atleast one unique selector. Can you share your url?

Comment: its locked for public :/ [link] www.nuovamoda.fashion try it

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

1. You can use `JavaScript:Void(0);` in your links like : `<a href="JavaScript:Void(0);">My menu1</a>`
2. ```
   <a id="mymenu1" href="some-link">My menu1</a>
   <script>
       document.getElementById("mymenu1").addEventListener("click", function(event){
           event.preventDefault()
       });
   </script>
   ```